# barchart does not contain a definition for datasource

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am getting an error on my barchart: `does not contain a definition for datasource` and another error `barchart does not contain a definition for valuememberX and valuememberY`.

```
public void BindGrid()
{
    // Load the name of the stored procedure where our data comes from here into commandtext
    string CommandText = "enterprise.spCollectionAlerts";

    // get the connection ready
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandTimeout = ConfigSettings.SqlCommandTimeout;

    SqlParameter workParam = new SqlParameter();

    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // Set the input parameter, companyid, branchid, departmentid
    // these parameters are set in the sub page_load
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CompanyID;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@BranchID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = BranchID;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DepartmentID;
    // open the connection
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    BarChart1.DataSource = reader;
    BarChart1.Series[0].ValueMemberX = "ProductName";
    BarChart1.Series[0].ValueMembersY = "TotalPurchase";
    BarChart1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You need to actually show us your code or we can't help.

Comment: am really sorry ..i have added it.

Comment: this is the html code for the barchart.   <asp:BarChart ID="BarChart1" runat="server"  ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth = "450" 
        ChartType="Column" ChartTitleColor="#0E426C" Visible = "false"
        CategoryAxisLineColor="#D08AD9" ValueAxisLineColor="#D08AD9" BaseLineColor="#A156AB">
    </asp:BarChart>

Comment: kindly guys help me on this..am really stuck